# How to load every record of a table into separate file?

Tags: linux, oracle, unix, plsql, ksh

Example: If the below query

```
Select * from emp;
```

Fetched 30 records..
Output as :

```
EMPNO   ENAME    JOB        MGR     HIREDATE    SAL     COMM  DEPTNO

7499     ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    20-FEB-81   1600    300    30

7521     WARD    SALESMAN    7698    22-FEB-81   1250    500    30

.....(more 28 records)........
```

Every record should be saved in a separate file with file name as 'Empno.Ename'

Comment: the question is tagged with `linux`, `unix` and `ksh`, so I've posted an `awk` solution; if the solution must be performed completely in (PL/)SQL then the post should be updated to state this (and also remove the `linux`/`unix`/`ksh` tags)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you will need to do the below

1. Create n number of files, since you want each record to be saved in each file of its own
2. Run through all the records
3. Save the data from each record in its own file and close the file

   ```
   DECLARE
   file_name VARCHAR2(30) := NULL;
   out_file UTL_FILE.file_type;
   dir_path VARCHAR2(100) := NULL; -- Give the directory alias, where you want to store file
   BEGIN

   FOR record IN
   (
       SELECT *
       FROM emp
   )
   LOOP
       file_name := TO_CHAR(record.empno) || '.' || TO_CHAR(record.ename);
       out_file  := UTL_FILE.fopen (i_chr_dir_path, file_name, 'W', 32767);
       UTL_FILE.put_line(out_file, record.empno || ',' || record.ename || ',' || record.job
       -- more fields
       );

       IF UTL_FILE.is_open (out_file) THEN
           UTL_FILE.fclose (out_file);

       END IF;

   END LOOP;
   END;
   ```

Comment: You could update this now to reflect the added requirement that the file names are of the form 'Empno.Ename'

Comment: @TonyAndrews   

Answer (score 1):

Here is one of the options. You simply generate a file with a select statement for each row in a table and then execute it.

Here I have a table named `T1`, wich contains 7 records. The file(let's name it `tabletofiles.sql`) looks like this:

```
set feedback off;
set termout off;
set heading off;
set verify off;
set sqlblanklines on;

# temp file with statements
spool /tmp/tmpfile.sql

# specify column names you want to fetch explicitly
select 'spool /tmp/file_' || to_char(rownum) || ';' || chr(10) ||
       'select c1
            from (select q.*
                      , rownum as rn
                    from &1 q )
           where rn = ' || to_number(rownum) || ';' ||
       chr(10) || 'spool off;'
  from &1;

spool off;

@@tmpfile.sql
#clean up after ourselfs
!rm -I /tmp/tmpfile.sql
```

Pass table name in as a parameter

```
SQL> @/tmp/tabletofiles.sql t1
```

After execution completes the `tmpfile.sql` contains the following:

```
spool /tmp/file_1;
select c1
            from (select q.*
                      , rownum as rn
                    from t1 q )
           where rn = 1;
spool off;

spool /tmp/file_2;
select c1
            from (select q.*
                      , rownum as rn
                    from t1 q )

           where rn = 2;
spool off;
```

...

The result of each `select` statement spooled into a different file.

And here are our final files:

```
 82 Jun 26 11:28 file_1.lst
 82 Jun 26 11:28 file_2.lst
 82 Jun 26 11:28 file_3.lst
 82 Jun 26 11:28 file_4.lst
 82 Jun 26 11:28 file_5.lst
 82 Jun 26 11:28 file_6.lst
 82 Jun 26 11:28 file_7.lst
```

Answer (score 1):

Assumptions:

- ignore the first line of column headers
- all data for a given `emp` record resides on a single line (eg, no embedded carriage returns in the data, data doesn't span multiple rows)
- test data is in a file named `emp.raw`
- `awk` is a valid option (OP is tagged with `linux`, `unix` and `ksh`)

Contents of sample emp.raw:

```
EMPNO   ENAME    JOB         MGR     HIREDATE    SAL     COMM   DEPTNO
7499     ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    20-FEB-81   1600    300    30
7521     WARD    SALESMAN    7698    22-FEB-81   1250    500    30
```

A 1-line `awk` solution:

```
$ awk '!/^EMPNO/ { print > $1"."$2}' emp.raw
```

And the results:

```
$ ls -1
7499.ALLEN
7521.WARD
emp.raw

$ for f in 7*
> do
> echo "+++++++++++++ $f"
> cat $f
> done
+++++++++++++ 7499.ALLEN
7499     ALLEN   SALESMAN    7698    20-FEB-81   1600    300    30
+++++++++++++ 7521.WARD
7521     WARD    SALESMAN    7698    22-FEB-81   1250    500    30
```

Comment: The data is coming from a database table and not a file :)

Comment: @SudiptaMondal: sure, the data is coming from a database table, but at some point the data can be written to a file; alternatively the output from the `select` could be piped into the `awk` solution; if the OP wants a purely (PL/)SQL solution then that should be added to the post